How to get the node's coordinates after force layout in Apache ECharts?
I use Apache Echarts which is a great library to display my graph but it has a drawback: if using force layout then I can't organize the nodes, after I dragged one of them in to a different position, the force layout moves it back to its original position.
I read several blog post and a possible (only one?) solution can be to leave the force layout to display the graph, then use 'none' layout and set the coordinates of 'force' layout to each nodes.
To do that I should be able to get the coordinates of the nodes after the 'force' layout displayed them. and then I could set X and Y coordinates and set the layout to 'none'.
Any hint please how can I get the coordinates in Apache Echarts?
Thanks!
